# Why is my code producing duplicate data?

Tags: python

Below is the code I am using to search through files for a particular string. When I open the results file it produces, my results are there.

But -- they are duplicated quite a few times and for the life of me I can not figure out why.

```
import os
global file_list

filename = raw_input("Enter a portion of the file name(s) you would like to search in: ")
results = raw_input("What file would you like results saved to: ")

file_list=[]
FO = open(results, 'w')

for dirname, subdirlist, files in os.walk("."):
    for filenames in files:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filenames)
        file_list.append(file)
        if str(file).find(filename) >= 0:
            for line in file:
                FI = open(file, 'r')
                for line in FI:
                    if len(line.split(':')) > 30:
                        line_list=line.split(':')
                        if line_list[29] == '5':
                            FO.write(line)
print("Files save to " + ("\"") + results + ("\""))
```

Comment: Probably better to use regex.

Comment: `for line in file:`? `file` is still the name of the file here, you have never opened that file.

Comment: sorry just edited it. Now its my actual code.

Comment: that line is still there.

Comment: @silentkow Why are you iterating over the filename? Remove that and you're done.

Comment: sorry which line is that?

Comment: Please click edit under your question and edit to add the following: contents of a short file or pair of files to be scanned, input and output to program that makes it scan the file(s), why the output isn't correct.  Thanks.

Comment: @silentkow: *that - used to refer to a person, thing, idea etc that has already been mentioned or is already known about*

Comment: You have `for line in` twice.  In the first case `file` is a string filename, and python will break it up into characters for you.  Since you never use these characters, it is  probably incorrect and would cause varying amounts of duplicates. For examples, the file "data123" would generate the same result 7 times, because there are 7 chars in "data123".  Is that actually in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have `for line in` twice.

In the first case `for line in file` refers to `file`, a string filename. When python encounters a for loop over a string, python will break the string up into individual characters and execute the loop once for each character.

Since you never use these characters, it is probably incorrect and would cause varying amounts of duplicates.

For examples, the file "data123" would generate the same result 7 times, because there are 7 chars in "data123".